# Send file from one user to another using using node.js and html5

Tags: html, node.js

I was creating a chat app using node.js, all things i m able to do but not able to get proper method to send files. 
I need to send file from one user to other and wants to create skype like experience using node.js and html5.

please help.

Many Thanks in advance.

Comment: any answer please let me know i am also facing this issue

Answer (score 0):

You could use sockets.io to push the file location to the user, or update a db when someone 'sends' a file, and the person that should get it uses a timed ajax post to query the db to see if they have a file to download.

I don't know if I'd trust users enough to allow them to send any kind of files over my server though.  I also don't know if sockets.io can stream bytes from one user to another in order to avoid having to store the file on the server.